# how to display leaflet map in specific div tag?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, vue.js, leaflet

i am trying to display leaflet map but i need to display map in specific div tag using id like document.getElementById("map") like this, i have given code below and i am using vuejs.

below is my div tag to render map

```
         <div id="map">
         </div>
```

below  is my script

```
         mounted () {
            //    L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'assets/vendor/leaflet' TODO: make it work with webpack
            Leaflet.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/images'

            let map = Leaflet.map(this.$el).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)

            Leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            }).addTo(map)

            Leaflet.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
              .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
              .openPopup()
          },
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Vue, but normally you don't need to make a document.getElementById ("map").
you just have to pass the id in L.map like that

```
let map = Leaflet.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)
```

And you have to give a height to your div "map", for example

```
 <div id="map" height="500px">
 </div>
```

**Edit**

What's wrong ? on my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leafletimageoverlay-6f7do) you can see an example in html and javascrip which is displayed normally. Here is a link to a tutorial that uses [Leaflet and Vuejs](https://youtu.be/2i2zL7jWm4c)